# expand textarea which ALREADY contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I've read all the posts here about textareas - and, yes, I too feel that it's been beat-to-death... but I've got a situation which I can't find a post about and it's driven me crazy for 5 days now.
Situation:
Multiple (hundreds of) textareas with a normal state of display:none which become visible as needed.
I save work in process via a database... and re-open the form to continue entering data. (yes, there's code to change the display state if the textareas have data in them - but that's not relevant to the situation.
I currently have a very good widget for expanding my textareas AS I ENTER the data - my problem is that when I re-open the form the textareas go back to their initial height.

I've attempted creating a function which processes ALL textareas when the form loads by triggering the keyup event in all of the textareas - but it doesn't make them expand... however, if I simply click into the field and then use an arrow key they open right up. Unfortunately this is NOT an option... like I said HUNDREDS of textareas.
Here's the code I've got for the keyup event / trigger:

```
    $("textarea").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            var target = $(this).attr("id");
            var tElement = document.getElementById(target);
            GrowUP(tElement);
        });
    });

    $("textarea").trigger('keyup');
```

and the code for my expansion of textareas:

```
    function GrowUP(oTextArea){
        var nMaxChars = 2000;
        var nTextLength = oTextArea.value.length;
        setTextAreaHeightWidth(oTextArea);
        if (nTextLength >= nMaxChars){
            oTextArea.value = oTextArea.value.substring(0, nMaxChars);
            return;
        }
    }

    function setTextAreaHeightWidth(oTextArea){
        var nTA5Height = 20;
        var nTextLength = oTextArea.value.length;
        var sTextAreaType = oTextArea.className;
        var nHeight;
        var nWidth;
        if (sTextAreaType.indexOf("long") >= 0){
            nHeight = nTA5Height;
        }
        // setting default height for the text area
        oTextArea.style.height = nHeight + "px";
        if (nTextLength > 0 && oTextArea.scrollHeight >= nHeight){
            oTextArea.style.height = oTextArea.scrollHeight + "px";
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0){
                oTextArea.style.height = oTextArea.scrollHeight + 20 +"px";
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm open to any suggestions. 

 
OK - update: 
I've found a way to fool JSFiddle into having the data already entered in the field... 
 Just select the 2nd checkbox to get it to show the textarea.
The textarea opens in the initial height - which I need to be the EXPANDED height (and it SHOULD if the code I wrote actually worked!)
P.S. In JSFIDDLE, under "Frameworks & Extension" you have to make sure it says "No wrap - in " ... it's been automatically changing this to "On DOM ready" which doesn't work!
 Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/MitchinThailand/fqcppux8/6/

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and simple fix, instead of triggering the `keyup` event in your `afterOnLoad()` function, trigger it after the switch statement in your `Summary(obj)` function. 
Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uwzo25fs/1/

In general, just trigger the event(s) that modify element heights AFTER you have stopped hiding the corresponding element(s).

Comment: sorry - I attempted your solution in my actual form - the problem is that it only expanded after some other interaction with the DOM. I'll have to setup my fiddle to do a better job of demonstrating what I want... get  back to you when I've got a better example.